# Trouble running JavaScript in browser emulator in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I have a simple question yet I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere. I am currently trying to run a simple set of code in Visual Studio in the emulator (Chrome), but when my JavaScript is executed, the browser instantly refreshes and I lose my changes.

```
<html>
<body>

    <p id="para1">my text</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">submit</button>

    <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var text = document.getElementById ("para1").style.color = "blue";
            }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So when my button is clicked, my paragraph text turns to blue for half a second then goes back to black right after the browser refreshes automatically. How can I fix this so the text stays blue until I manually refresh the browser?

Comment: What is `var text = document.getElementById ("para1").style.color = "blue";` supposed to do? That's not how you assign a value to something. Try removing `var text = `.

Comment: @CodeF0x it's code from a tutorial. Not sure why it's assigned to a variable but I'm sure there's a reason later on.